# Audit table and foreign key

Tags: foreign-key, azure-sql-database, audit

I have a database with multiples tables that must be audited.

As an example, I have a table of objects defined with a unique ID, a name, and a description.

The name will always be the same. It is not possible to update it. "ObjectA" will always be "ObjectA".

As you see the name is not unique in the database but only in the logic.

The rows "from", "to" and "creator_id" are used to audit the changes. "from" is the date of the change, "to" is the date when a new row has been added and is null when it is the latest row. "creator_id" is the ID of the user that made the change.

```
+----+----------+--------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+
| id |   name   | description  |         from         |          to          | creator_id |
+----+----------+--------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+
|  1 | ObjectA  | My object    | 2021-05-30T00:05:00Z | 2021-05-31T05:04:36Z |         18 |
|  2 | ObjectB  | My desc      | 2021-05-30T02:07:25Z | null                 |         15 |
|  3 | ObjectA  | Super object | 2021-05-31T05:04:36Z | null                 |         20 |
+----+----------+--------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+
```

Now I have another table that must have a foreign key to this object table based on the "unique" object name.

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| id |   foo   | object_name |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 | blabla  | ObjectA     |
|  2 | wawawa  | ObjectB     |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

How can I create this link between those 2 tables?

I already tried to create another table with a UUID and add a column "unique_identifier" in the object table. The foreign key will be then linked to this UUID table and not the object table. The issue is that I have multiple tables with this problem and I will have to create a double number of tables.

It is also possible to use the object ID as the FK instead of the name but it would mean that I must update every table with that FK with the new ID when updating an object.

Comment: The name in 1st table is not unique so you cannot refer to it (formally you may but this will be ambiguous reference). So refer to definite row using the reference to table1.id and retrieve object name by the reference. Of course you may store the name in 2nd table as overdefined data nevertheless if you'll find this justified and useful, but not as referenced value. Alternatively you may create additional table with object names and refer both tables to it.

Comment: If I am referring to the id, it would mean that I would have to change the foreign key value every time I am updating an object table because it will create a new ID

Comment: If so then either do not use FK at all (use client-level referencing, by the conditions hardcoded in the queries only). Or use AFTER INSERT trigger over 1st table which will update references in 2nd table.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with an additional table to have this final design:

> Table "Object"

```
+-------+--------------------------------------+---------+--------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+
| id PK |            identifier FK             |  name   | description  |         from         |          to          | creator_id |
+-------+--------------------------------------+---------+--------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+
|     1 | 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000 | ObjectA | My object    | 2021-05-30T00:05:00Z | 2021-05-31T05:04:36Z |         18 |
|     2 | 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-524887451057 | ObjectB | My desc      | 2021-05-30T02:07:25Z | null                 |         15 |
|     3 | 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000 | ObjectA | Super object | 2021-05-31T05:04:36Z | null                 |         20 |
+-------+--------------------------------------+---------+--------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+
```

> Table "Object_identifier"

```
+--------------------------------------+
|              identifier PK           |
+--------------------------------------+
| 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000 |
| 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-524887451057 |
+--------------------------------------+
```

> Table "foo"

```
+-------+--------+--------------------------------------+
| id PK |  foo   |         object_identifier FK         |
+-------+--------+--------------------------------------+
|     1 | blabla | 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000 |
|     2 | wawawa | 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-524887451057 |
+-------+--------+--------------------------------------+
```